# Track Custom event using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, gtag.js

I am trying to track user feedback onclick of thumpsUp(1) or thumsDown(0) : [image] with help of GA but not able to track the events in the Analytics Dashboard as shown below.

```
      window.ga("send", {
        hitType: "event",
        eventCategory: "button",
        eventAction: "feedback",
        eventLabel: pageID, // page url
        eventValue: value,  // 1 or 0
      });
    }
```

custom event is not appearing below:

[image]

I am able to get events : [image]
Is it possible to map vote and pageID together so that we can know which page has which vote

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown is for Universal Analytics but dashboard is on GA4.

They are 2 different things.

You can find code to setup GA4 events in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events?client_type=gtag

To understand who clicked on up/downvote you can use the parameters associated with the event:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/event-parameters?client_type=gtag

Note: the data in the GA4 platform (unlike UA) are visible after 24h.

Comment: Thanks for the answer : gtag('event', 'send_feedback', { 'vote': value 'pageID': pageID, }); now feedback appears in the Realtime section , but is it possible to map together pageID and vote so that we can know which page has up/downvote